# Overlay different datasets in same facetted plot in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to gather two facet columns into one column with ggplot2.

In the following example, I need to overlay the content of the two columns DEG and RAN into one, while giving different colours to DEG and RAN data (small points and smooth line) and provide the corresponding legend (so I can distinguish them as they are overlayed).

I feel my code is not too, too far from what I need, but the relative complexity of the dataset blocks me. How to go about achieving this in ggplot2?

Here's my code so far:

```
require(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)

fileName = paste("./4.csv", sep = "") # csv file available here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/bm9hd0t5ak74k89/4.csv?dl=0

mydata = read.csv(fileName,sep=",", header=TRUE)

dataM = melt(mydata,c("id"))
dataM = cbind(dataM,colsplit(dataM$variable,pattern = "_",names = c("NM", "ORD", "CAT")))
dataM$variable <- NULL
dataM <- dcast(dataM, ... ~ CAT, value.var = "value")

my_palette <- colorRampPalette(rev(brewer.pal(11, "Spectral")))

ggplot(dataM, aes(x=NR ,y= ASPL)) +
geom_point(size = .4,alpha = .5) +
stat_smooth(se = FALSE, size = .5) +

theme_bw() +
theme(plot.background = element_blank(),
axis.line = element_blank(),
legend.key = element_blank(),
legend.title = element_blank()) +
scale_y_continuous("ASPL", expand=c(0,0), limits = c(1, 7)) + 
scale_x_continuous("NR", expand=c(0,0), limits = c(0, 100)) +
theme(legend.position="bottom") +
theme(axis.title.x = element_text(vjust=-0.3, face="bold", size=12)) + 
theme(axis.title.y = element_text(vjust=1.5, face="bold", size=12)) +
ggtitle("Title") + theme(plot.title = element_text(lineheight=.8, face="bold")) +
theme(title = element_text(vjust=2)) +
facet_grid(NM ~ ORD)
```

Here's what it gives me right now:

[image]

Extra question: how come DEG/SF doesn't show a smooth line?

Comment: I did not inspect your code line-by-line, but `NR` and `ASPL` end up as character after running it. You probably want them to be `integer` and `numeric` based on their values.

Comment: To answer the extra question: somewhere in the verbose warning output, `ggplot` is telling you that it does not have enough points to construct a sufficiently smooth curve for one of your facets. I suspect it's this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `group` aesthetic to define that data points with the same value of `ORD` belong together. You can also map aesthetics `shape` and `color` to this variable. You can also use `.` to specify that the facets are not split along a specific dimension.

I have made the changes to your code below after transforming `NR` and `ASPL` to numeric variables:

```
dataM$NR <- as.integer(dataM$NR)
dataM$ASPL <- as.numeric(dataM$ASPL)

ggplot(dataM, aes(x=NR ,y= ASPL, group=ORD, color=ORD)) +
  geom_point(size = .7,alpha = .5, aes(shape=ORD)) +  ## increased size
  stat_smooth(se = FALSE, size = .5) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(plot.background = element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_blank(),
        legend.key = element_blank(),
        legend.title = element_blank()) +
  scale_y_continuous("ASPL", expand=c(0,0), limits = c(1, 7)) + 
  scale_x_continuous("NR", expand=c(0,0), limits = c(0, 100)) +
  theme(legend.position="bottom") +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(vjust=-0.3, face="bold", size=12)) + 
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(vjust=1.5, face="bold", size=12)) +
  ggtitle("Title") + theme(plot.title = element_text(lineheight=.8, face="bold")) +
  theme(title = element_text(vjust=2)) +
  facet_grid(NM ~.)
```

Comment: This is fantastic ilic! Thanks so much! As far as the extra question goes, is there any ways to force it to draw a line, even if a little less precise than it should be?

Comment: Take a look at the help for `stat_smooth` and `gam` (which is the method it's trying to use) on how to reduce the number of knots. You need to pass the smoothing method some argument.

Comment: using method = "loess" in stat_smooth fixes the extra problem!

I have another big question about this graph, I'll make another question... Thanks so much once again Ilir.